# X server crashes when I try to change dual-display orientation

Tags: x11, gnome, fedora-25, xrandr

Ultimately I am trying to mirror my displays, but no matter how I try, doing so will crash my system (at least the X server, and I can't seem to get it running again) so I have to reboot.

I recently set up a dual-monitor system running Fedora 25.  I log in to my user with the GNOME on Xorg option selected.

So my output when I run `xrandr` is the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

This all looks correct, but when I try `xrandr --output DP-2 --same-as DP-1` one of my monitors goes blank, and the other monitor no longer responds to clicks or any other interaction.

The output of `xrandr --output DP-2 --same-as DP-1 -v --dryrun` is the following:

```
xrandr program version       1.5.0
crtc 1: disable
screen 0: 1920x1080 506x285 mm  96.25dpi
crtc 0:    1920x1080  60.00 +0+0 "DP-2"
crtc 1:    1920x1080  60.00 +0+0 "DP-1"
```

There are no config files under `/etc/X11/` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with most of the machines in the work-group.  When we upgraded to a higher version of Fedora, the issue was fixed.